# bootstrap accordion plus sign isn't updating

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two bootstrap accordions and on each one inner accordion. first one is opened by default. when i click on second one, first ones icon isn't updating to plus.

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zctb27au/12/)

also only one accordion must be opened, on my local it works, but in jsfiddle no, I don't know why.

**.css**

```
.panel-title {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 50px !important;
}

.panel-title::after {
  content: "\f067";
  color: #3a3a3a;
  left: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "FontAwesome"
}

.panel-title[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: "\f068";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are using bootstrap version 3.3.7.
If you upgrade your fiddle with the version 4.6.0, it should work fine.

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o71n3r90/)